# Expected mapping trying to configure IP in ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, netplan

I have this configuration file for `01-netcfg.yaml` (I tried the `50-cloud-init.yaml` too) and nothing works.

I get an error like this:

```
Error in network definition /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 0 column 8: expected mapping
```

My file:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
enp0s3:
dhcp4: no
dhcp6: no
addresses: [192.168.12.246/24]
gateway4: 192.168.12.1
nameservers:
addresses: [127.0.0.53, 8.8.8.8]
```

Any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

yaml is a structured format that uses indentation to indicate structure.  Your pasted file shows that all your lines are left-aligned in the first column.  It looks like you've lost the whitespace when copying some example, you will need to add it back.